# Laravel paginate resources won't add meta

Tags: php, laravel

I have resources data returning in JSON. When I try to get my data with paginate it is not included meta data.

Based on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#pagination) my data supposed to be included meta like:

```
"meta":{
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "path": "http://example.com/pagination",
    "per_page": 15,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 10
}
```

but my data is returning like this:

[image: one]

## Code

`controller`

```php
public function index()
{
    $products = ProductFrontResource::collection(Product::orderby('id', 'desc')->with(['photos', 'seo', 'tags', 'variations', 'variations.children', 'options', 'options.children', 'categories'])->where('active', 'yes')->paginate(8));
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $products,
        'message' => 'Products retrieved successfully.',
    ]);
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: I think you have to use pagination function with this also: ProductFrontResource::collection (another query->paginate(8))->paginate(8);

Comment: @MubasharIqbal sorry didn't get what you mean! would you give a sample please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `response()`. Laravel's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.

Every resource class defines a `toArray` method which returns the array of attributes that should be converted to JSON when sending the response.

```php
public function index()
{
    $data = Product::orderby('id', 'desc')
        ->with(['photos', 'seo', 'tags', 'variations', 'variations.children', 'options', 'options.children', 'categories'])
        ->where('active', 'yes')
        ->paginate(8);

    $products = ProductFrontResource::collection($data);

    return $products;
}
```

#### Additional Meta Data

> 'message' => 'Products retrieved successfully.'

Yes, you can [**Adding Meta Data**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data).

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'message' => 'Products retrieved successfully.'
    ];
}
```

Comment: thank you it's working but i think you need to edit `return $product;` to `return $products;`

Comment: what if I want to transform collection? according to docs I could override toArray method right? but when I do that it gives me an error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id
```